# Installed orbot and orweb but still no connection with android tablet

Tags: orbot

I have a nexus7 1st gen, 4.4.2 android. I just get a red cross on orweb saying I am not using it. Are there settings I should be using?

Comment: Same here (Nexus 5 / 4.4.2), I only get FF + Proxy Mobile to work, but I'd rather have a secure Browser, not just anonymity...

Comment: i have android 3.3.3 torrent downloaded to my device and still no connection with any tor

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm suspecting that Orbot has crashed my ZTE E7+ mini pad :(

Comment: This does not answer the question. Also, *any* app could crash your device. It's not necessarily Orbot's fault.

Answer (score 6):

Orweb is broken on Android 4.4.x due to the fact that Google removed proxy setting support in their WebKit component.

We have a new browser coming based on Firefox, but it is not quite ready yet.

Your option are:

1. Use Firefox with our "privacy enhanced configuration" documented here: https://guardianproject.info/apps/proxymob/ (*WARNING*: this should be considered more private but NOT anonymous)
2. Root your device and use transparent proxying to run all apps, browsers through Orbot/Tor. You should also use "Incognito" mode in Chrome, Firefox, etc if you do this.
3. Be a very, very early alpha tester of Orfox, our new browser, with development builds here: https://guardianproject.info/builds/Orfox/latest/

Comment: If you use Firefox for Android with Tor, go to `about:config` and set `media.peerconnection.enabled` to `false` or you’ll have [your real IP address exposed](https://diafygi.github.io/webrtc-ips/ "Your real IP address can be exposed using WebRTC.
See here for a demo.").

Comment: I'm getting the same error in Android 5.0.2; is Orweb permanently broken on Android?

Answer (score 2):

Orbot has been updated on Google Play Store and here:
https://guardianproject.info/releases/Orweb-release-0.5.2.apk

with a fix for KitKat!

Answer (score 0):

Mine also said that I wasn't using Tor, what you have to do is go to the settings on orbot which allows you to choose which apps to run through Tor and select Orweb

I Hope you find this useful :-)